# auto fix errors when removing a user control property

Tags: c#

When I remove a user control property that I have created and used in a project. There will be as many errors as times I have used control in project. For example imagine I have user control and it has a property named `p1`. when I remove `p1` I get errors saying myusercontrol.p1 doesn't exist.

Is there a way to get rid of them automatically?

Comment: What should happen to the code that was using that property? Using ReSharper you can perform a "Safe Delete", but I sense you've got more problems if you need this.

Comment: Whaaaaaaat? Can you post your code instead?

Comment: @choz my question is completely clear and I see no reason to explain more because it just makes it more complex

Comment: @CodeCaster. Yeah it worked thank you. you can post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a property, go ahead and do so - and fix all errors you find after that.

You could use ReSharper's Safe Delete, but that'll do little if you actually used the property:

```
var foo = someClass.PropertyToRemove;
bar.CallMethod(someClass.PropertyToRemove);
```

The code was there for a reason, and ReSharper cannot figure out for you what that code should become if you remove `someClass.PropertyToRemove`.